Access filtered PrimeNG table data for custom csv export
I'm used to using exportCSV() on my p-table, but I'd like to get that same csv data from multiple p-table grids and combine them into a single CSV file. I need to be mindful of any column filters applied so I can't just use a copy of the data used to build the p-table. The exportCSV() function handles the filters but it doesn't let me access the data.
